# ¿Hay una forma de mostrar TODAS las categorías en un sólo category.php?

Tags: wordpress, bucles, wordpress-theme

Resulta que hice mi custom post y todo está funcionando como se debe, pero he agregado las categorías y subcategorias y al entrar en cualquiera de ellas mi `category.php` se muestra vacío, es decir, no muestra ninguna categoría.

Esto es lo que contiene mi category.php:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Category
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- Sección de Noticias Recientes -->
    <div class="album">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
            <h2 class="pt-3">Categorías: </h2>
            <hr>

              <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <!-- Entrada -->
                    <h4 class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-2 pb-2 text-justify">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-2 pb-2 text-justify">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Entrada -->
              <?php  endwhile; endif; ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

            </div>
          </div>

        <!-- Barra Lateral -->
          <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <!-- End Barra Lateral -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Sección de Noticias Recientes -->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Tengo algunas paginas de categorias personalizadas y todo se muestra correctamente usando el mismo loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Pero ese mismo loop **NO muestra** las categorías en `category.php`

¿Cual será mi error?

### Actualización

En un principio el tema era que no podía ver los posts dentro de las categorías en category.php, al parecer son sólo algunos posts.

Después de probar varias cosas que están funcionando en este momento he notado que mi tipo de publicación actual al parecer no está registrando las categorías.

Me explico,

Hice un `custom post type` y sus `custom fields` con `ACF` y `CPT UI` para un tipo de publicaciones específicas. He estado agregando las categorías correspondientes a cada una de esas publicaciones. Al parece todo iba bien hasta el momento en que entraba a cualquiera de las categorías del post, con lo cual abre una pagina (exactamente abre `category.php`) y tan solo muestra el nombre de la categoría, pero no muestra `ningún post agregado` a esa categoría.

¿Cual fue la prueba que hice?

Bien, estoy agregando artículos a la pagina principal mediante las `entradas` que vienen por defecto en wordpress, he agregado varias categorías a esas entradas e hice una pagina de categoría personalizada para un tipo de categoría en particular (`category-cipsoft.php`), la cual muestra correctamente las entradas dentro de la categoría `CipSoft` sin ningún problema. En este caso todo marcha perfecto.

Ahora bien, para las publicaciones del custom post que hice con ACF y CPT también hice una pagina de categoría personalizada llamada `category-magias.php` que es exactamente una copia de `category-cipsoft.php` (que muestra los artículos perfectamente) pero en este caso no me funciona con `category-magias.php`, la página se queda en blanco.

El loop que he usado para ambos archivos es el mismo, con la única diferencia en el `nombre de la categoría`, para la primera es `CipSoft`, para la segunda es `Magias`:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'cipsoft', 'posts_per_page' => 300 ) ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
...
<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

Ahora viene lo curioso y lo que `me hace pensar que el problema` está en el `custom post` creado con `ACF y CPT UI` y algún tema relacionado con las `categorías`, ya que en las pruebas estoy cambiando el nombre de las `categorías` y solamente muestra los posts de la `categoría` `CipSoft` pero NO los de la `categoría` `Magias`.

Lo lógico sería que también mostrara las publicaciones de magias cuando el nombre de la categoría sea `magias`, exactamente como lo hace cuando coloco la categoría `cipsoft`.

Notese que la categoría `magias` sí tiene publicaciones agregadas, al igual que `cipsoft` que tiene 7 publicaciones, por lo tanto no es por falta de publicaciones, ya que sí se "registran" en las categorías.

Por lo tanto pienso que el problema viene del custom post que tuve que hacer, ya que con las entradas no ocurre ningún problema para mostrar las publicaciones en sus categorías. En cuanto a CPT me aseguré de añadir compatibilidad con las taxonomías registradas disponibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos, single.php, category.php, archive.php son archivos que enlistan post, no enlistan las categorías, es decir, el archivo category.php enlista los post de una categoría especifica o varias según la solicitud del usuario, para mostrar una lista de categorías debes de usar una función hecha para eso, por ejemplo, la función wp_list_categories(); para mostrar un listado de todas las categorías agrega el siguiente código en el archivo functions.php del tema:

```
function category_list() {
    echo "<ul class=" . 'sidebar-list' . ">";
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'orderby'            => 'id',
        'style'               => 'list',
        'show_count'         => 0,
        'title_li'            => __( '<div class="clase">Categorias</div>' ),
        'use_desc_for_title' => false,
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ));
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Luego basta con poner el código `<?php category_list(); ?>` en cualquier parte de tu sitio para mostrar la lista de categorías, por lo general esto se hace en el sidebar del tema.

**Actualización**

Los custom post se excluyen de la pagina de categoría de manera predeterminada, por lo que para agregarlos en la consulta deberá hacer uso se la función `pre_get_posts` de wordpress agregando el siguiente código en su archivo de funciones.

```
function custom_post_type_in_category($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_category()) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'tu post type' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_post_type_in_category');
```

Fuente: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163901/custom-post-type-not-visible-on-category-page

Comment: es un gusto leerte. Voy a actualizar la publicación ya que estoy probando unas cosas y ocurre algo extraño con las categorías de cierto tipo de publicaciones.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, verifique si le funciona

Comment: Bien, hice la prueba agregando el post-type y sigue sin funcionar. También probé con un loop normal y no funciona (ya lo había probado anteriormente). Efectivamente ocurre lo que mencionas, wordpress está evadiendo las categorías de los custom posts. Con las categorías fuera de los custom posts funciona correctamente.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, verifique de nuevo

Comment: Ahora si!! Incluso agregué los otros post types que hice antes. Todo funciona correctamente. Muchísimas gracias por tu maravillosa ayuda.